# Why don't I get a 'cross-thread operation not valid' for ALL members in the Form?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ui-thread

I'm getting a 'cross-thread operation not valid' in one member but not in another and both belong to the same Form, the same UI thread I believe. Those members are `uxServerGroup` and `uxServerListen`. When I change the text on `uxServerGroup.ValuesSecondary.Heading` it works fine, I don't get a cross-thread exception. But I do get one when I try to enable back the `uxServerListen` button. **Why**?

I should probably note that both of those components belong to Krypton Toolkit, they are not standard Windows Forms.

Here's a sample of the code I have:

**MainForm.cs:**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form {
    public MainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        SomeClass.ObjectStateChanged += new ObjectStateEventHandler(SomeClass_ObjectStateChanged);
    }

    private void uxServerListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        uxServerListen.Enabled = false;

        ClassHandler ch = ClassHandler();
        ch.Initialize();
    }

    private void SomeClass_ObjectStateChanged(Enum e1, Enum e2) {
        switch(e1) {
            case E1.TypeA:
                HandleTypeAObjectChanges(e1);
                break;
            case E1.TypeB:
                HandleTypeBObjectChanges(e2);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void HandleTypeAObjectChanges(Enum e2) {
        switch(e2) {
            case E2.ModeA:
                uxServerGroup.ValuesSecondary.Image = Resources.StatusSuccess16;
                break;
            case E2.ModeB:
                uxServerGroup.ValuesSecondary.Image = Resources.StatusFailure16;
                uxServerListen.Enabled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**SomeClass.cs:**

```
public delegate void ObjectStateEventHandler(Enum e1, Enum e2);

public static class SomeClass {
    public static event ObjectStateEventHandler ObjectStateChanged;

    internal static E1 e1;

    internal static void ObjectStateChanged(Enum e2) {
        if(ConnectionStateChanged != null) {
            ConnectionStateChanged(e1, e2);
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassHandler.cs:**

```
public class ClassHandler {
    public ClassHandler() {
        // (...)
    }

    public void Initialize() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void SomeMethod() {
        SomeClass.ObjectStateChanged(E2.ModeB);
    }
}
```

After a lot of searching, I ended up fixing it like this:

```
private void SomeClass_ObjectStateChanged(Enum e1, Enum e2) {
        if(InvokeRequired) {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
                switch(e1) {
                    case E1.TypeA:
                        HandleTypeAObjectChanges(e2);
                        break;
                    case E1.TypeB:
                        HandleTypeBObjectChanges(e2);
                        break;
                }
            }));
        }
    }
```

As an additional question, can someone explain me this (the thing inside `MethodInvoker`):

```
new MethodInvoker(() => { /* (...) */ })
```

Comment: Because the exception is only generated when Winforms *knows* that it is unsafe.  It knows by your code using the Handle property.  Like the Enabled property setter does.  It does not know that any properties you added yourself are thread unsafe, it assumes you did it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting a 'cross-thread operation not valid' in one member but not in another

Invalid cross-thread operations need to be specifically detected to trigger a usable exception. If there is no detection, you won't get that exception. But be careful: don't take that as permission to access the property from another thread, it's still not usually allowed, and the few exceptions will be documented as thread-safe.

> As an additional question, can someone explain me this (the thing inside MethodInvoker):
>
> ```
> new MethodInvoker(() => { /* (...) */ })
> ```

This creates an anonymous inline method, and when called, the `/* (...) */` statements will be executed. A `delegate` is then created to make the method callable, and that's what gets passed to `Invoke`. Usually, it can be easier to write it slightly more elaborately like so:

```
MethodInvoker foo = () =>
{
    ...
};
// no part of the ... above has run yet
if (!control.InvokeRequired)
    foo(); // call foo directly
else
    control.Invoke(foo); // let the UI thread call foo
```

Comment: About my main question... Although I was using threads, I was also using an event/delegate to fire some events to `MainForm`. I thought that was thread-safe... **I guess it's not?** About `MethodInvoker`, got it :) Thanks for the different approach :)

Comment: @RicardoAmaral Delegates run on the thread that invokes them. If you make sure an event is always fired from the UI thread, the event handler will also run on the UI thread, but if you call it from a different thread, it'll run in that same thread.